# How can I reach the elements in the array which I created in the struct ? SWIFT 5

Tags: arrays, json, struct, swift5

I have an array which is in the struct.

`struct UserModal:Codable {

```
var username:String? 
var name:String?
var lastname:String?
var state:Int?
var accessPoints:[Int]?
```

}`

and this is my json codes which I get users info. I can print variables in here.

```
func connectionsWithService(userName:String,passWord:String){
    
    
    
    let url = url_user
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, err) in
        print(url)
        
        if err != nil {
            
            print(err.unsafelyUnwrapped)
            
        }else {
            
            do{
                
                let user  = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserModal.self, from: data!)
                
                print("Kullanıcı Username : \(String(describing: user.username ?? nil))")
                print("Kullanıcı Name :\(String(describing: user.name ?? nil))")
                print("Kullanıcı Last Name :\(String(describing: user.lastname ?? nil))")
                print("Kullanıcı State :\(String(describing: user.state ?? nil))")
                print("Kullanıcı Points :\(String(describing: user.accessPoints ?? nil))")
```

But I need to access, accessPoints array in another viewController. So I create a variable like

```
var accessPoints:UserModal?
accessPoints?.accessPoints!
```

When I try to get accessPoints data it returns nil. I try to get elements with for loop or append another array but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also I save these values in userDefaults in dictionary type. But also when I try to  get it returns nil too. When I print all data it print like {
    

    accessPoints =     (
        2,
        4,
        19,
        22,
        35,
        36,
        38,
        99,
        112,
        113,
        114,
        120,
        127,
        128,
        129,
        130,
        131,
        132,
        403,
        470,
        477,
        478,
        479,
        480,
        600,
        601,
        602,
        604,
        700
    );

Answer (score 0):

you may have to init value in structure like below

```
  struct UserModal:Codable {
    var username:String?
    var name:String?
    var lastname:String?
    var state:Int?
    var accessPoints:[Int]?
    
    init(username: String, name: String, lastname: String, state: Int, accessPoints: [Int] ) {
        self.username = username
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.state = state
        self.accessPoints = accessPoints
    }   
}
```

init value like

```
UserModal(dictionary or Data)
```

Comment: Hi. I create an array and append  like  self.generalUserArray.append(UserModal(username:  user.username!, name:  user.username!, lastname: user.lastname!, state: user.state!, accessPoints: user.accessPoints!)) then this time when ı try to print array elements with for loop it all return nil.. But before append ı can print all info like user.username

Comment: how can you print element?

Comment: @cemsezeroglu you don't need to use the UserModal constructor again because of your user variable is already UserModal type, so you only need to append that variable in the array in this way. generalUserArray.append(user). If you continue having problems with accessPoint you should review then two things before appending. First one it is not nil, ant then is an Int type array.